# Problemas con mi formulario ShowDialog vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

estoy realizando una aplicación en **VB.NET** y tengo una complicación que no me había percatado. Resulta que de un formulario principal [`frmInventario`] realizo una operación a través de un procedimiento y muestro el resultado en otra ventana `frmCoincidentes`, para abrir dicha ventana utilizo el método `showDialog()` de `VB.NET`

Al abrirlo por primera vez todo me va Excelente, pero cuando cierro el formulario frmCoincidentes y lo vuelvo a abrir ya no me realiza la operación que deseo.

Asi es la forma como abro el frm

```
Private Sub btnVerAdicionales_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnVerAdicionales.Click
        LlenarExistencias()
        llenarUNION()

        If CInt(frmCoincidentes.DataGridView2.Rows.Count) > 0 Then
            frmCoincidentes.ShowDialog()
        Else
            MsgBox("Falta Informacion.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Info Adicionales")
        End If
    End Sub
```

> NOTA: Para cargar los datos de nuevo, tengo que cerrar la aplicacion
>   por completo y luego volver a abrirlo.

Comment: que es la operacion que deseas? que no realiza?

Comment: Un procedimiento para pintar los reglones de un dataGridView, al inicio lo hace bien pero al abrirlo otra ves ya no  me lo realiza, tengo que cerrar por completo la aplicacion y abrirlo nuevamente para que me vuelva a realizar la operación

Comment: Como cerras el modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una POSIBLE solución.
Tuve un evento similar, y lo que me solucionó el problema fue que en el evento FormClosed del formulario modal llamé el método `Dispose` para **DESTRUIR POR COMPLETO** las instancias del mismo.

```
Private Sub frmCoincidentes_FormClosed(...) Handles Me.FormClosed
    Me.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Aveces cuando se `"Cierran"` los formulario modales, más que cerrar el formulario lo que en realidad se está haciendo es ocultarlo, lo que no desencadena ningún evento de cierre. Como el formulario está oculto, puede mostrarse nuevamente sin necesidad de crear una nueva instancia del mismo.

Ahi podrá causar el conflicto de que no calcula los datos que deseas.

Comment: Depende como cierres el modal, o no modal, puede que no lo estes cerrando si no solo ocultando. Esto depende de como se llame al cierre. Mas que el dispose hay que llamar al close del formulario.

Comment: Me funciona esta respuesta, antes cerraba el modal con el famoso X existente en la esquina superior derecha. No se si eso se deba el error @gbianchi ?

Comment: Esa X deberia hacer un close del formulario, pero tal vez se quedaba colgado porque en tu evento de cierre impedias el cierre. Lo que haces con ese dispose es forzar el cierre, aunque este tratando de hacer cosas.

Comment: Y existe otra forma de solucionar sin ocupar el dispose? Siento que cuando cerraba la aplicación por completa tambien forzaba el cierre . @gbianchi

Comment: con el close. y revisando que no haya procesos o clases dentro de tu formulario que impidan el cierre

Comment: He checado cual es el proceso que me impide cerrarlo, pero no veo nada raro,  [esto es todo lo que tengo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n0yFEg) en la clase `frmCoindicentes`